# Traverse an array using a for loop to see if shape entered matches user entered info

Tags: c#, arrays, traversal

I am having issues figuring out how to traverse an array using a for loop. my array is supposed to check if the user entered the correct shape either square or circle and return `UNKNOWN` if not found. I'm having issues getting the else part to work.
This is what I have so far. My for loop also has to iterate from 0 to the last element in validation array.

```cs
//finds the shape based on user input
public static String findMyShape(String command)
{
    //needs to have a for loop
    //should return unknown if no values found
    var myStringArray = {"circle", "square"};
    var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
    for(var i=0; i<arrayLength; i++)
    {
        return(myStringArray[i]);
    }
    else
    {
    }
    return "UNKNOWN";
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't even compile. there is no if for the else statement

Answer (score 1):

```
//finds the shape based on user input
public static String findMyShape(String command)
{
//needs to have a for loop
//should return unknown if no values found
    var myStringArray = {"circle", "square"};
    var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        if (command == myStringArray[i])
            return command;
    return "UNKNOWN";
}
```